# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. (Forbidden (403)) DJANGO

Tags: python, django, security, token

I'm trying to get POST from 2 diferents dropdown, I had get the parametres from the POST, but i get problems with the CSRF token ....

index.html

```
<form method="post" action="/getdata/">{% csrf_token %}
    <select name="Lista">
        <option selected="selected" disabled>Objects on page:</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>

    <select name="Lista2">
        <option selected="selected" disabled>Objects on page:</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>    
    <input type="submit" value="Select">    
</form>
```

in spite of I use the csrf token in my html form, it didn't worked ...

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render

from view.forms import *
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from view.models import *



def index(request):   
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        Lista = request.POST.get('Lista')
        print "Lista 1 "+Lista
        Lista2 = request.POST.get('Lista2')
        print "Lista 2 "+Lista2

        #FORMS
        form = FormsLista(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():                
            newPost = Lista(num_lista_1=Lista, num_lista_2=Lista2)                
            newPost.save()              
            context = {                    
                'Lista': Lista,
                'Lista2': Lista2
            }       

            return render(request, 'showdata.html', context)
    else:

        template = loader.get_template('index.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Lista (models.Model):
    num_lista_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    num_lista_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.num_lista_1
```

I have the cookies activated by the way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [Django's CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it), you need to render the template with the request object:

```
template = loader.get_template('index.html')
return HttpResponse(template.render(request=request))
```

Your code would be more consistent if you used `render` everywhere:

```
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

To fix the `[view] didn't return an HttpResponse` error, you need to make sure that the index view always returns an `HttpResponse`. At the moment you return `None` for POST requests when the form is not valid. It is very common in Django to do the following:

```
def index(request):   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    form = FormsLista()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Then, in your template, you can display the form errors. See the docs on [rendering forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) for more info.

Comment: I tried both options ... but I get this error **The view tutorial.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.** ...

Comment: That's a separate issue. As the error suggests, you always need to return a response. Look at what happens when `if request.method == 'POST':`, but the form is not valid.

Comment: It worked! ... but I don't understand why always my POST is not valid ... some idea?

Comment: If you look at `form.errors` it should give you a hint. If you're still stuck, please ask a new question because it's a separate issue.